# Why are binary numbers are less complex to convert to hex, than decimal? (for PCs)

Tags: binary, numbers, hex

I've been told this :

"Computers convert binary data into the hexadecimal (hex) number system because
it is much less complex than converting data into decimal numbers."

Why it is less complex?

Comment: What?  Could you give an example?

Comment: That last word is a killer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computers don't "convert" binary to hex any more than they convert binary to decimal. Anything but binary to a modern computer is just "for human comfort". (This isn't *entirely* true, [IEEE 754 base 10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) is a counter-example.)

Binary and hex are rather easily convertible because a hex character is exactly 4 bits (one of 16 values, 0-15) and two hex characters are 8 bits (one octet). This nice property is not true for decimal as one decimal digit is "3 bits and some change" (one of 10 values, 0-9) -- there is no pretty alignment.

(See Howards answer for the hand-math and examples).

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

I support you mixed up binary and decimal in the title. In order to convert a binary into hex you only have to build groups of for and do a substitution for each block:

```
b110010011100 => 1100 1001 1100 => xC9C
```

In order to convert decimal to hex you'll have to apply divisions and mod calculations:

```
d1234 => 77*16 + 2 => (4*16 + 13)*16 + 2 => x4D2
```